# Laravel file storage URLs work locally but 404 on a real server

Tags: php, laravel, url, laravel-5

I'm working with a custom file storage disk and it works as expected on my local machine, but on my Forge server the generated asset URLs don't work.

My filesystem config looks like this:

```php
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    'assets' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public/assets'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/assets',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

];
```

I have a file at `{myapp root}/storage/app/public/assets/file.jpg` and I'm generating URLs with `Storage::disk('assets')->url('file.jpg');` and this works fine, it gives me the expected URL, which is (locally) `myapp.test/assets/file.jpg`. In production I get the correct URL as well, `myapp.com/assets/file.jpg`, but this link 404s. If I insert "storage" into the URL, so that it's `myapp.com/storage/assets/file.jpg`, it works.

I've `php artisan storage:link`ed everything in both environments, everything else is *exactly* the same, but on a real server the URLs all 404.

**UPDATE SEP 2020**

I have a much simpler filesystem setup now, but IIRC the solution here in the end was just to symlink `public/assets` to `storage/app/public/assets` on the Forge server. At the time this was ugly to do automatically, but in Laravel 7+ (maybe earlier too) there's a new `links` key in `config/filesystems.php` that makes this very easy.

In general, I wouldn't recommend nesting public disks/symlinks like this though. I should have just put things in `storage/app/assets` and kept it flatter overall.

It's still a mystery to me why this all appeared to work fine locally...

Comment: is symlink(Storage shortcut folder ) created in public directory with valid permission to read and write ?

Comment: If you have `'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage'` then `->url` will also append `storage` at the end. You claim it doesn't so maybe the configuration is a bit messed up

Comment: @ViperTecPro I just did Laravel's built in `php artisan storage:link`. I think I understand the issue here with the symlinks and URLs... but why is it working locally? If I have *not* symlinked `public/assets` to `storage/app/public/assets`, why does `myapp.test/assets/file.jpg` work?

Comment: Maybe because server has disabled symlink for security reason.